# Unstable wired internet connection under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have recently got a new notebook and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. For some months, everything worked just fine, but then suddenly the Ethernet connection "broke". It's not like I can't connect to the internet at all, it's more like it's extremely unstable. It feels a bit as if something tried to squeeze through a bottleneck: If the connection gets through, it's as fast as network and ethernet adapter allow (up to 1 GBit) - but most of the time I run into time out errors. I can also replicate this with the speed test of our local supercomputing center (http://ping.lrz.de/speedtest/). Once in a while I get the full speed both upstream and downstream, the next time I get only 30% bandwidth in one direction, the next time the speedtest won't start at all, i.e. the page http://ping.lrz.de/speedtest/ does not update the numbers.

Funny thing: The WiFi connection works flawless. And the Ethernet connection works fine with other (Windows-based) computers.

Here's some info:

```
lshw -C network

....
*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 30
   serial: 68:84:7e:6a:fb:4d
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:148 memory:92300000-9231ffff
*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: wwp0s20f0u5i12
   serial: 2a:f8:15:92:14:3f
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes


inxi -Fxxxz

....
Network:   Card-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:9df0
       IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
       Card-2: Intel Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM
       driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6 chip-ID: 8086:15bd
       IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
....


lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM [8086:15bd] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Fujitsu Client Computing Limited Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM [1e26:001a]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

One solution I've already tried is to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

But this hasn't had any effect after rebooting. Is there anything else I could try? This is quite an annoying problem...

P.S.: Of course, I have checked whether the cable is the problem - it is not!

UPDATE:

Did a packet loss test at [packetlosstest.com](https://packetlosstest.com/). Did it twice, using default settings. First time: Total packet loss of 49.7%. Minutes later: total packet loss of 0.0%. This is exactly the instability I am experiencing.

I also checked out `dmesg | grep e1000e`. It returned

```
[    1.988998] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.988999] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.989340] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.068698] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    2.135741] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 68:84:7e:6a:fb:4d
[    2.135741] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.135870] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    2.136406] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[   14.066731] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

My kernel is (`uname -rv`):

```
5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020
```

Comment: "And the Ethernet connection works fine with other (Windows-based) computers", same cable? If not, have you tried a different cable?

Comment: "30% in one direction" - 30% what ? Bandwidth ? Packages ? Do you expierience packet loss or higher round times ? "Speedtest won't start at all" - what kind of test are you using ? ioperf ? How does it not start at all - errors, warnings ? Please update your question with these details

Comment: @mgor: Yes, different cable was tried. Robert Riedl: question updated.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dmesg | grep e1000e` specifically after the system has been running for a few minutes and you have experienced the issue? That is an Intel network card so should be using the e1000e driver. If the driver is having issues it should be logged to dmesg but this is reset on reboot. This is why it is necessary to let the system run long enough to experience the issue before checking the log. Also, what kernel version are you running? `uname -rv`

Comment: SO you test this with only one pingcheck but it does affect your whole internet experience ? Have you talked to the support of your ISP ? The page you use is not ideal, since it doesn't show things like packetloss.. I'd suggest a site like this: https://packetlosstest.com/ where you can also configure packet sizes. Another thing - regarding the "not starting" bit could be a DNS issue

Comment: @RobertRiedl no, I suffer from weeks of bad experience, file a ticket with the local computing center, have all cables and connections checked, cross-check with different computers and different operating systems AND use this one pingcheck. THIS does affect my internet experience. I did a packet loss test now and updated the question.

Comment: Wow, thats some heavy packet loss right there. So the `dmesg` doesn't show anything... and you basically rules out everything else with your tests. You can try to upgrade the driver for your ethernet device. Your version is 3.2.6 while the current release is 3.6.0 [link to driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005480/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html)

Comment: If you don't want to go through the trouble of compiling a network driver, you could also try rolling back to an older kernel. If this started happening suddenly, it could have been the result of the upgrade to 5.3. It's pretty easy to test and pretty low risk. You can simply pick an older version from the grub menu at boot. I would recommend going all the way back to 4.15.x. 4.15 is the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS kernel and will be supported through the life of 18.04. You can see your installed kernels by `ls /boot`. If you don't have 4.15, you can install it with `sudo apt install linux-image-generic`

Comment: My first shot would be the MTU. Maybe the MTU for wireless/windows is 1500 and Lunux WLAN tries to set jumboframes (9000)? See `ip a list eth0` ... The next step would be to check the routing. Is `ip r` (nearly) the same for wireless and wired connection? ... And than i would also check `netstat -s`, if it depends on the protocol ... An we all love thermal problems, if it is good/bad/good/bad, could you take a look at the mainboard temperature? Maybe with `lm-sensors`?

Answer (score 0):

I had network packages break a few years ago.

1. Make a Live USB [Linux Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
2. Plug it into the affected machine and load into it.
3. Download the packages you need [from here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) (I have forgotten just how I pulled all the right ones for my hardware, sorry. Leaving work shortly).
4. Store them to the hard drive.
5. Boot back into your hard drive and install them via a package manager.

   Alternatively, you can possibly install drivers [from here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/82185/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I219-LM) but you might need to compile them yourself.

Hope this helps and maybe at the least gets you in the right direction. o7